# Why is this infinite recursion?

Tags: php

Just ask the title asks, here's the code:

```
<?php

$foo = 0;

function letsLoop() {
    while ($foo != -1) {
        changeFoo();
        echo "Hello, world!\n";
    }
}

function changeFoo() {
    extract($GLOBALS);

    $foo = -1;
}

letsLoop();
```

Comment: Because variable's scope.

Comment: extract is dangerous, use with extreme caution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just because you extract the global into the local scope doesn't mean that you will be modifying the global variable `$foo`.  To reference the global variable inside the function, you *must* use the `global` keyword:

```
function changeFoo() {
    global $foo;

    $foo = -1;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, global does NOT equal to extract(), that's a lesson learned. Will mark as correct answer when timeout happens.

Comment: Also try `$GLOBALS['foo']`